# REACT: How to update list after click button EDIT?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have main component App which display category list. This list I get from server and dispay in view table in component Table.

Component App also have children component `ChangeCategory`. Using this component I can change title of some category.

### Home.js:

```
const App = () => {

  const [value, setValue] = useState({
         list: [],
   });
useEffect(() => {
async function fetchData () => {
     const response =  await fetch(`путь`);
     const data = await response.json();
     setValue({
         list: data.data
    });
};
}, [])
 return (
    <div>
        <Table data = {value.list} />
        <ChangeCategory />
    </div>
```

After request in Home.js I  get this response from server:

```
{"data": [ 
 {"title": "bmw", "description": "good"},
 {"title": "tesla", "description": "good"},
 {"title": "ford", "description": "good"} ]}
```

### ChangeCategory.js (edit title using method PUT in form):

```
const  ChangeCategory = (props) => {
    const { /..... } = useFormik({  
      initialValues: {
          title: '',
      },
    onSubmit: async (formValues) => {
        const response = await fetch(`somepath`, {
           method: PUT,  
        } ) 
        const data = await response.json();  
       }});

   return (    
    <div>
      <form >   
       <input type="text"> </input>
          <button type="submit">Edit</button>
     </form>
   </div>);};
```

After request in Home.js I get this response from server:

```
{"model":  {"title": "mercedes","description": "good"} }
```

That is, in the response I get only what I edited and the new model title.

But I have problem:

### After editing in the form my Title and clicking on the submit button, my list is not updated!

#### It only updates when I reload the page in the browser. And I need me to immediately see the title update in the list.

How to update list after click button EDIT?

Comment: You never set data after updating the list, you never call fetchData so there should not even be a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React only re-renders components under [certain conditions](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating), such as if a prop of the component is updated. But you can always tell a component to update based on another condition.

Since you are already implementing the [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook, you could set a rerender condition by adding a variable to the second argument of the hook (right now it's just an empty array which is also a valid argument) ~ any variable you put inside the array will trigger a re-render if its value changes.

Consider adding a boolean to the components state, shouldUpdate, and when the button is clicked set that to true. Then have it set back to false whenever the component renders.

Comment: glad to hear that!